# && operator not stopping excution with nil

Tags: ruby

The class below defies my understanding that `nil && 'foo'` should return nil and not execute 'foo'

no matter what I tried, with or without parenthesis, `@user.another_boolean` always returns undefined method another_boolean for nil nilclass. I thought if @user is nil it should stop evaluating there and return nil.

```
class MyClass
  def initialize(user, variable = nil) 
    @user = user
    @variable = variable || user.try(:variable)
  end 

  def result
    @result ||= !!(@user &&
                   @variable &&
                   @variable.a_boolean ||
                   @user.another_boolean? ||
                   @user.a_third_boolean? && instance_method_retuning_a_boolean)
 end
end
```

I also tried to look for the documentation of the && operator inside the ruby documentation but could only find a reference to `and` which shouldn't be the same thing given their precedence difference.

Any help much appreciated.

Ruby version: 2.2.5

Edit:
@user and @variable are rails model

Rails version: 4.2

Comment: Your question is confusing: _another_boolean_  .... You never invoke a method by this name. The only thing I see is that you call a method `another_boolean?`. Please always post the exact error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is standard practice in software for `&&` to have a higher precedence than `||`.

So the following are all logically equivalent:

```
b && a || c
a && b || c
c || b && a
c || a && b
```

Now, your code is a little longer:

```
@user &&
  @variable &&
  @variable.a_boolean ||
  @user.another_boolean? ||
  @user.a_third_boolean? && instance_method_retuning_a_boolean
```

But again we can group the `&&` operators together to show what it's equivalent to:

```
(@user && @variable && @variable.a_boolean) ||
  (@user.another_boolean?) ||
  (@user.a_third_boolean? && instance_method_retuning_a_boolean)
```

Therefore if `@user && @variable && @variable.a_boolean == false`, then `@user.another_boolean?` will be evaluated.

I'm not clear what it is you're trying to achieve - so I don't know if the above logic is correct, or how one might "fix" it, but there's your explanation for why the method is being called.

Comment: Thank you this was a helpful explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression has a form of:

```
   aaa &&
   bbb &&
   bbb.foo ||
   aaa.bar ||
   aaa.baz && something
```

it may be reformatted as:

```
   aaa && bbb && bbb.foo
   ||
   aaa.bar
   ||
   aaa.baz && something
```

It's the same, just whitespaces are laid out differently.
As you can see here, not all terms are protected by the initial aaa&&bbb test.

Most probably you meant this:

```
@result ||= !!( (
                   @user && 
                   @variable
                )
                &&
                (
                  @variable.a_boolean ||
                  @user.another_boolean? ||
                  @user.a_third_boolean?
                )
                && instance_method_retuning_a_boolean
              )
```

I've added way too many parentheses than needed, but this way you exactly see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Yann and welcome to Stackoverflow. Let me give you some examples that may help you understand the reason for your observation.

You correctly stated that:

```rb
nil && true
=> nil
```

but if you chain additional operators without explicitly use brackets then the following happens:

```rb
nil && true || true
=> true
```

This is because the `&&` operator has higher precedence so you could write the same thing like this, and then its clear why the expression does not stop after the first nil:

```rb
(nil && true) || true
```

I found this article pretty helpful: https://womanonrails.com/operator-precedence-ruby.

So for your case if we would put the brackets as it is now we would have the following:

```rb
(@user && @variable && @variable.a_boolean) ||
                   @user.another_boolean? ||
                   (@user.a_third_boolean? && instance_method_retuning_a_boolean)
```

This means that even if the first part of the expression results in false, the `@user.another_boolean?` still gets evaluated.

So what you probably want is putting brackets explicitly:

```rb
(@user && @variable) && 
(@variable.a_boolean || @user.another_boolean? || @user.a_third_boolean?) &&
instance_method_retuning_a_boolean
```

So now you have the first part, which will check if both @user and @variable are not nil. If any of those is nil, the second part will not be evaluated anymore.

Hope this brings some clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably avoid an overly complex boolean expression by adding a *guard clause* (or two) that separates the prerequisite conditions from the actual result:

```
def result
  return unless @user
  return unless @variable

  @result ||= @variable.a_boolean ||
              @user.another_boolean? ||
              @user.a_third_boolean? && instance_method_retuning_a_boolean
end
```

I'm not sure if this returns the expected result, but you get the idea.